# Building macro with csname

Tags: enumitem, csname

How to expand `csname` properly? In the following MWE, I am trying to make a macro
that "binds" together `\prefixator` and `\afterator`. I want `\giveme{im}` to be equivalent to `\givemeim`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}                        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                       

\makeatletter                                  
\def\halo@re{Re}                               
\def\halo@im#1{Im}                             
\def\prefixator{halo@}                         

\newcommand{\giveme}{                          
    \edef\vv{\csname\prefixator\afterator\endcsname}
    \meaning\vv                                
}                                              

\newcommand{\givemeim}{                        
    \let\vv\halo@im                            
    \meaning\vv                                
}                                              
\makeatother                                   

\begin{document}                               
\def\afterator{im} %\def\afterator{re} works as expected                                 
\giveme                                        

\end{document}
```

I know that `\edef` in this can't work, because it tries to expand `\halo@im` but there is no argument. I tried everything with `\let` but it didn't work with `\giveme{re}`.

EDIT: actual problem
When `\SetEnumitemKey{sth}{unknownlabel=\arabic{enumi}}` is used there is created macro `\enitkv@enumitem@sth` with meaning : `\enitkv@setkeys{enumitem}{unknownlabel=\arabic{enumi}}`. In this case `prefixator` is `\enitkv@enumitem@`, and `afterator` is `sth`. (context is evil)

(buggy) MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}                              
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                          
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                             
\usepackage{enumitem}                                
\makeatletter                                        

\SetEnumitemKey{sth}{unknownlabel=\arabic{enumi}}    

% -- can't touch these                               
\def\prefixator{enitkv@enumitem@}                    
\def\afterator{sth}                                  
% --                                                 

\newcommand{\giveme}{                                
    % make a macro \vv \enitkv@enumitem@sth (bind them)
    % \let\vv\enitkv@enumitem@sth  
    \edef\vv{\csname\prefixator\afterator\endcsname{}} 
    \meaning\vv                                      
}                                                    
\makeatother                                        

\begin{document}                                     
\giveme                                                                                                   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `\csname`...`\endcsname` is correct. What you missed is that `\edef` will keep expanding whatever `\csname\prefixator\afterator\endcsname` returns, and *that* is when the code fails.

After one expansion step, `\csname\prefixator\afterator\endcsname` becomes `\halo@im`, and then you are left with `\edef\vv{\halo@im}`. One more expansion and you get the error message:

```latex
! Argument of \halo@im has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.24 \giveme

?
```

which is telling you that when TeX tried to grab the arguments of `\halo@im` it found a `}` too early, which caused the problem. You need to either **a)** remove the argument from the definition of `\halo@im` (*i.e.,* `\def\halo@im{Im}`, as you do with `\halo@re`), or **b)**, add a formal argument to `\halo@im` in the `\edef`: `\edef\vv{\csname\prefixator\afterator\endcsname{}}`. The first option makes more sense, since you are not using `#1` in `\halo@im`.

However if you just want a copy of some command under a different name, you can do:

```latex
\expandafter\let\expandafter\NewName\csname<command name>\endcsname
```

The first expansion step expands the first `\expandafter`, which skips over `\let` and expands the second `\expandafter` which, in turn, skips over `\NewName` and expands `\csname` (X is expanded, S is skipped):

```latex
% X           S   X           S       X
 \expandafter\let\expandafter\NewName\csname<command name>\endcsname
```

Once the expansion of `\csname` ends, you are left with:

```latex
\let\NewName\<command name>
```

which does what you want.

Comment: The problem is that  I can't touch `\halo@im`. My original problem (this is simplified version)  with `\enitkv@enumitem@<some key>` (enumitem package).

Comment: `\edef\vv{\csname\prefixator\afterator\endcsname{}}` solves problem for `\halo@im`, but enumitem's macro is more complicated, and when I do the same thing for it there pops up bug with `\fi` :-)

Comment: @CarolLypher It looks like you fell into the [XY-problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2449/134574) pit. You could use the second approach, provide an actual argument to `\halo@im` so that it won't complain: `\edef\vv{\csname\prefixator\afterator\endcsname{}}`. However, without the _real_ use case it's hard to give you anything helpful. Could you show what your _actual_ problem is?

Comment: @CarolLypher Note that using `\edef\vv{\csname\prefixator\afterator\endcsname{}}` when `\afterator` is `re` leaves a possibly-undesired `{}` in the input stream...

Comment: I wanted to ask more general question, because I thought it is just correct use of `expandafter` or `noexpand` will solve it. It is just `\let` to expanded csname.

Comment: @CarolLypher If you can't rely on the expansion of the macro and just want a _copy_ of it, then try `\expandafter\let\expandafter\vv\csname\prefixator\afterator\endcsname`.

Comment: Great! It is exactly what I wanted to do. I am trying to override enumitem bug message about undefined key, and change `\enitv@setkeys{enumitem}` to `\setkeys{myenumeratewrapper}` in `\meaning` string and than change it to macro :-)

Comment: @CarolLypher It looks like it's quite a task you are trying to do. Patching commands is... interesting :-) If you think you found a bug, please report in the [enumitem repo](https://github.com/jbezos/enumitem). Javier usually replies fast :-)